# Cast a (void const *x) to a (unsigned char const *y)

Tags: methods, types, parameter-passing

I'm going through a source code analyzing its implementations where I have a method defined :

```
unsigned int rs_calc_weak_sum(void const *p, int len) {
unsigned char const    *buf = (unsigned char const *) p;
}
```

What type of parameter should be passed into this method??

please help me.

thanks.

Comment: A pointer to anything. That's what `void*` denotes, after all.

Comment: Should be or can be?  It looks like it takes any constant pointer and recasts it as an unsigned char constant pointer.  Is that what it is supposed to do?

Comment: @Jim thanks. yes. I need to pass a char array. could you please give me an example?

Comment: @larsmans thanks. I got the idea. I need to pass a char array. please give me an example.

Comment: @Satthy: which language is this? C or C++?

Comment: sorry for late reply i'm using C++. and I still have that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any pointer can be passed to a void * parameter.   What 'should' be passed, depends on what the code does with that parameter.

```
char array[12] = "Hello World";
unsigned in res = 0;
res = rs_calc_weak_sum(array, 12);

#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void )
{
  char filename[] = "file.txt";
  FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );

  if (file != NULL) {
    char line [1000];
    while(fgets(line,sizeof line,file)!= NULL) /* read a line from a file */ {
      res = rs_calc_weak_sum(line, 1000);
    }

    fclose(file);
  }
  else {
    perror(filename); //print the error message on stderr.
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I need to get a block of chars from a file using getc. then i need to pass that block into this method. please provide me some sample code. thank you.

Comment: thanks. I already tried this one. but it gives me an error saying "undefined reference to rs_calc_weak_sum(void const*, int)"

Comment: Sounds like a linker issue.  What are you doing?